# Filter with url-pattern /* not mapped to all jsp's

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, struts2, servlet-filters

I am starting to learn struts 2. I have 3 pages, FirstLevel.jsp, SecondLevel.jsp, BadGuess.jsp. I want to apply filter in the three pages.

**LevelFilter.java**

```
package com.tutorialspoint.struts2;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.*;

public class LevelFilter implements Filter{

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("desroy");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("level filter");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("init here");
    }

}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
   id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

   <display-name>Struts 2</display-name>
   <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>FirstLevel.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>

   <filter>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <filter-class>
         org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
      </filter-class>
   </filter>
   <filter>
      <filter-name>Level Filter</filter-name>     
        <filter-class>
            com.tutorialspoint.struts2.LevelFilter
        </filter-class>
   </filter>
   <filter>
      <filter-name>Authentication Filter</filter-name>     
        <filter-class>
            com.tutorialspoint.struts2.AuthenticationFilter
        </filter-class>
   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>Level Filter</filter-name>     
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
   </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>Authentication Filter</filter-name>     
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
   </filter-mapping>





</web-app>
```

The three jsps are just composed of input stuffs. When I run FirstLevel.jsp, the message ("LevelFilter") in the console stacks, but when I submit the form (if correct, form will be submitted to Secondlevel.jsp, otherwise to BadGuess.jsp) the console does not produce a message. It should also produce a message in the console since I mapped the filter to all the jsps (/*).  Replies are greatly appreciated.

Edit:

I think the filter does not apply to the jsp's mapped by struts.xml? Because when I tried running directly `BadGuess.jsp` the message in the console shows, meaning `doFilter` is applied to it.

**struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
   <package name="magicwords" extends="struts-default">
      <action name="firstMagicWord" 
            class="com.tutorialspoint.struts2.LevelAction" 
            method="execute">
            <result name="success">/SecondLevel.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/BadGuess.jsp</result>
      </action>
   </package>
</struts>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You shouldn't be accessing JSPs directly in an MVC application. Those are your view, not your controller.

Comment: What do you mean with "accessing JSPs directly"? I'm sorry I'm just a struts 2 newbie.

Comment: At no point should the URL in the browser end with .jsp. That means that you are invoking the JSP directly and bypassing the Struts2 framework. Based on your question, it sounds like you are doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For filters to run on JSPs reached via forwarding (the default result type) you'd need to make sure the filter is running for forwarded requests:

```xml
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>theFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/the/pattern</url-pattern>
  <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher> 
  <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the order of your filters… They are invoked in the order in which they are mapped.

Try

```
  <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>Authentication Filter</filter-name>     
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
   </filter-mapping>
   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>Level Filter</filter-name>     
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
   </filter-mapping>
   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
```

your level filter won't be applied when the struts filter stops the chain for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

Could be your problem is related to using a **Deprecated** filter dispatcher:

The FilterDispatcher (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher) is used in the early Struts2 development, and it’s deprecated since Struts 2.1.3.

If you are using Struts version >= 2.1.3, it’s always recommended to upgrade the new filter class – StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter).

**Instead of**:

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
       <filter-class>
           org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
       </filter-class>
</filter>
```

**Try using**:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
         org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
        </filter-class>
</filter>
```

Comment: That shouldn't affect how the container executes filters, though.